# Wordpress IXR_Date wrong date

Tags: php, wordpress, strtotime

This is my php code:

```
echo date('m/d/Y h:i:s A T'),"<br>";
$match_date = strtotime(date('m/d/Y h:i:s A T'));
echo "match_date= ", $match_date, "<br>";

$test = new IXR_Date($match_date);
print_r($test);
```

But return wrong month and day value:

```
08/19/2012 07:38:10 AM PDT
match_date= 1345387090
IXR_Date Object ( [year] => 2012 [month] => 2012 [day] => 2012 [hour] => 07 [minute] => 38 [second] => 10 )
```

Whats wrong? How can I use IXR_Date properly?

Answer (score 1):

Use `time()` function instread of `strtotime` over `date`:

```
$test = new IXR_Date(time());
```